# iOS UICollectionViews and autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have hit a slight problem with UICollectionViews.  I have posted a question before here but I think I have moved bit -

[UICollectionView - Autolayout with pinterest style layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391911/uicollectionview-autolayout-with-pinterest-style-layout)

Objective -

UICollectionview with a custom positional layout with the cells using auto layout.

Current state of play:

I currently have a LayoutView which inherits from UICollectionViewLayout. In my PrepareLayout() I am looping around my collection of items and create a list of attributes which I then return via the LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect depending on the rectangle.

Also during the PrepareLayout I use "prototype" cells (cells that are used only to get the correct size and not part of the UI). I populate the cells with the data and then ask the cell for the minimal height.  The width is calculated based on how wide my current item needs to be - i.e. if it spans a number of columns.

Issue:

So my problem that I have hit is that my cells consist of multiple labels that are multiline (0 lines). I have created constraints attached to the ContentView top, left, right and bottom but I can't seem to get the label to wrap correctly.  I know that UILabel requires the PreferedMaxWidth to be set but my problem is that my cell is going to have a UIImageView beside the label so I don't think I can calculated the available space that remains.

Could anyone lend a helping hand or point me in the general direction of where to find some more information?

Comment: Have you ever gone through the "Pinterest Style Layout Tutorial" on Ray Wenderlich's site? https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2

Comment: Yeah, apologises I probably should have state that - I have that was my original starting point but unfortunately it is the auto layout side of things that appears to be causing me the issues.

Comment: hmmm... it's been quite a while since I looked at that, but I thought it *was* using auto-layout?

Comment: hmm... maybe i am missing something really obvious then.  I will double check.

Comment: Just checked... I guess it's using auto-layout for the positioning, but it's calculating the height with `NSString boundingRect with size`... is that not sufficient?

Comment: I was trying to stay away from having to do any sort of calculation as there are multiple labels and spacing etc to take into account. It isn't complicated just hard to maintain - change of the layout means changing the calculations etc.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to auto-layout the UICollectionViewCell purely, check out the [CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout) instead.

Comment: Yeah, i am calculating the width manually and using auto layout to get the height.  Here is a slightly more detailed post.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/270843